# Can I run a function against a specific element in my custom item renderer?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

Im trying to figure out of I can take the data in a RichEditableText element inside my custom Item renderer and run that data through a function and then have the results of that function show in the RichEditableText component for all the items in the item renderer...

my item renderer looks like this:

```
<!--    *********************************************** -->     
<s:DataGroup id="myDataGroup" width="100%">
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
    </s:layout>

    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:ItemRenderer width="100%">
                <s:HGroup width="100%">
                    <s:BitmapImage id="labelIMG" source="{data.user.profileimage}"/>
                    <s:VGroup width="100%">
                        <s:RichEditableText id="labelText" 
                                            width="100%"
                                            editable="false"
                                            fontSize="16"
                                            multiline="true"
                                            paddingRight="20"
                                            selectable="false"
                                            text="{data.text}"
                                            textJustify="distribute"
                                            verticalAlign="middle"
                                            lineHeight="14"
                                            letterSpacing="-5"/>
                        <s:Label id="labelDate" fontSize="9" 
                                 width="100%"                                                                                                                    
                                 textAlign="right"
                                 text="{data.date_created}" 
                                 paddingBottom="20" 
                                 paddingRight="20" />
                    </s:VGroup>
                </s:HGroup>
            </s:ItemRenderer>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
</s:DataGroup>
<!--    *********************************************** -->
```

so for the date item im showing in the item renderer (labelDate with the bound data data.date_created)  I'd like to run this through a function that converts date to the desired format...   the function is in the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282144/twitter-created-at-value-into-friendly-time-format-at-flash).

is this possible?   Note: Im also generating my dataProvider data from JSON, and have to first make the data an ArrayCollection:

```
myJSONdata = JSON.parse(jsonContent.data);   //PARSE THE INCOMING JSON DATA
arrColl = new ArrayCollection(myJSONdata as Array);   // CONVERT IT TO AN ARRAYCOLLECTION
myDataGroup.dataProvider = arrColl;   // NOW ASSIGN IT AS THE DATAPROVIDER FOR DATAGROUP/ITEMRENDERER
```

is it possible to alter the incoming data at the point where Im converting to an ArrayCollection so the data that gets used in the item renderer already has this date function run and has replaced the date element?

If BOTH are possible is there one that is better for performance or generally considered a best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and not too hard.  In short, add the function to your itemRenderer and call it in a dataChange() event listener or in the set data method.

```
        <!-- add the data change listener here -->
        <s:ItemRenderer width="100%" dataChange="onDataChange()">

            <fx:Script><[[

              // add in your date format function
private function toRelativeDate(d:Date):String {
        var now:Date=new Date();
        var millisecs:int=now.valueOf()-d.valueOf(); //gives you the num. of milliseconds between d and now
        var secs:int=int(millisecs / 1000);
        if(secs < 60) {
            return secs + " seconds ago";
        }else if(secs < 60*60) {
            return Math.round(secs / 60) + " minutes ago";
        } else if(secs < 60*60*24) {
            return Math.round(secs / (60*60)) + " hours ago";
        } else {
            return Math.round(secs / (60*60*24)) + " days ago";
        }
    }

              // implement the data change listener here
              protected function onDataChange():void{
                  // make sure that the data exists; as sometimes this method will run during intiial component setup
                  if(data){ 
                   // if data does exist; cast it as a date pass it to your parsing function and set the result of that to the text field of your RichText control
                   labelText.text = toRelativeDate((new date(data.text)));
                  } else {
                     // if data doesn't exist; set the text of the RichText control to empty.
                    labelText.text = '';
                   }
              }

            ]]></fx:Script>

            <s:HGroup width="100%">
                <s:BitmapImage id="labelIMG" source="{data.user.profileimage}"/>
                <s:VGroup width="100%">
                    <s:RichEditableText id="labelText" 
                                        width="100%"
                                        editable="false"
                                        fontSize="16"
                                        multiline="true"
                                        paddingRight="20"
                                        selectable="false"
                                        <!-- do not set the text value using Binding -->
                                        textJustify="distribute"
                                        verticalAlign="middle"
                                        lineHeight="14"
                                        letterSpacing="-5"/>
                    <s:Label id="labelDate" fontSize="9" 
                             width="100%"                                                                                                                    
                             textAlign="right"
                             text="{data.date_created}" 
                             paddingBottom="20" 
                             paddingRight="20" />
                </s:VGroup>
            </s:HGroup>
        </s:ItemRenderer>
```

I wrote all this code in the browser; so it may need tweaking.  As a general rule; I recommend using the dataChange() event instead of binding to set values of inside an itemRenderer.  Binding can have some performance/memory leakage side effects.

Comment: Ahhhhh, thanks a lot... the ondatachange is neat and even better if helps with performance and avoiding the side effects you mentioned.  will be putting this to use ALOT!

everything looking good, but for some reason the date conversion function is telling me the d (date im passing to it) is null.... looking into that now.  i really appreciate your help.

Comment: My conversion code code was probably wrong.  You may try Date(data.text) to see if that helps.

Comment: cant for the life of me get it figured out...  for some reason the following produces null:

    labelDate.text = toRelativeDate(data.date_created as Date);

so that what the toRelativeDate function receives is null and it breaks and shows error...

the date thats coming from my data provider looks like this:  Sat Apr 06 21:10:21 +0000 2013

Comment: Got it... should have been as follows:  
labelDate.text = toRelativeDate(new Date(data.created_at));   thanks for your help.

Comment: I updated the code for the proper conversion.  If this completely answers your question; be sure to mark it as answered with the green checkbox and/or upvote it.